# Parsing (multidimensional) arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I wan't to write a parser which would return the original (multidimensional) array for

```
double[][] returned = parse2D(Arrays.deepToString(new double[][]{{1,2}{3,4}}));
```

Similarly, I would want the method `parse1D`, and the method `parse3D`, which would depend on the other parsers.

There are several problem which I'm running into while coding this.

- `Scanner` will give tokens such as "[1" and "4]"
- `Scanner` using `useDelimiter("[(\\s*,\\s*)]")` won't retain the structure of multidimensional arrays
- I seem to be unable to get a single `Pattern` to let a `Matcher` capture the right groups
- Moreover, I shouldn't write my own parser for a `double`.

The following code I have vomitted out (written) kind of works, but also accepts Strings such as `"random crap before actual array [1]"`

```
public static Tuple<Matcher, double[]> parse1D(String input) {
    Pattern left = Pattern.compile("\\[");
    Pattern right = Pattern.compile("\\]");
    Pattern comma = Pattern.compile(",\\s*");
    Pattern num = Pattern.compile("[[0-9]+E\\.\\-]+");

    Matcher matcher = left.matcher(input);
    matcher.find();
    List<Double> l = new ArrayList<Double>();
    matcher.usePattern(num);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        MatchResult result = matcher.toMatchResult();
        l.add(Double.parseDouble(result.group()));
        matcher.usePattern(comma);
        matcher.find();
        matcher.usePattern(num);
    }
    double[] ret = new double[l.size()];
    int x = 0;
    for (double d : l) {
        ret[x] = d; x++;
    }
    return new Tuple<Matcher, double[]>(matcher, ret);
} // the matcher is also returned to be used by parse2D...
```

This should be so simple! Why can't I get this simple thing to work?!
Should I write a parser myself? Should I get some parser-combinator library?
What to do?

Comment: What are you using the parse for? Is there a reason you couldn't just serialize into JSON and then back out?

Comment: @ericBarr I am currently still learning JSON. It seems to provide me with the necessary equipment. I'm now trying it with `javax.json.stream`, but I'm running into some problems. Thanx for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;

public class JSONtry {

private static double[] parse1D(JsonParser parser) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Double> l = new ArrayList<Double>();

    outerLoop:
        while (parser.hasNext()) {
           JsonParser.Event event = parser.next();
           switch(event) {
              case START_ARRAY: break;
              case END_ARRAY:
                  break outerLoop;
              case VALUE_STRING:
                  l.add(Double.parseDouble(parser.getString()));
                 break;
              default:
                  throw new IOException("Not a 1 dimensional array! Seeing: "+event.toString());
           }
        }
    double[] ret = new double[l.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i<l.size(); i++)
        ret[i] = l.get(i);
    return ret;
}
private static double[][] parse2D(JsonParser parser) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<double[]> l = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    outerLoop:
        while (parser.hasNext()) {
            JsonParser.Event event = parser.next();
            switch(event) {
            case START_ARRAY:
                l.add(parse1D(parser)); 
                break;
            case END_ARRAY:
                break outerLoop;
            default:
                throw new IOException("Not a 2 dimensional array! Seeing: "+event.toString());
            }
        }
    double[][] ret = new double[l.size()][l.get(0).length];
    for (int i = 0; i<l.size(); i++)
        ret[i] = l.get(i);
    return ret;
}
}
```

Btw: I am using `getString(.)` instead of `getInt(.)` or `getBigDecimal(.)` since I want to allow `NaN` and `POSITIVE_INFINITY` values.

An optimization is possible for multidimensional array parsing, since after the first array, we know what the length of other arrays will be.